# Scrolling message board, how do I link to an id in a div within a div?

Tags: php, html, css

Ok so this might be very basic but I'm struggling here.

I've got limited space but I need a comments board so I need to be able to scroll through messages. I've got my database and php setup and the messaging works fine. I've done the layout with div's so that all the comments are within the master comments div with is set to overflow: hidden, hiding the messages that don't fit. Every message is then formed as a div (which has 2 div's inside for subject/sender and comment sections). Each of the message div's is automatically given an id by the script so I have something to target here.

What I would like to do is to have the messages scroll so that when you click 'down', the topmost message will disappear and the messages will move in line so that the next one is now topmost. Is this possible? I tried to play around with childNodes but couldn't get it to work.

Also, does my layout solution make any sense? Should I change it to lists?

CSS is

```
#kommentit { // <- all comments
position: absolute;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 475px;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;}

.sitoja { // <- this is the single comment binder
position: relative;
width: 400px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 0;}
```

I assign id for every message so I get

```
<div class="sitoja" id="[i]">
```

in php

```
echo '<div class="sitoja" id="'.stripslashes($info2->id).'">';
```

You can view the dummy of the message board here: http://pohjis.site40.net/testi.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

The simplest is changing `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: scroll;`.

You can also `display: none;` the topmost comment to make the lower ones move up.

And you can scroll the div with javascript.

BTW, with some adjustment of the css you don't need `position: absolute;` - not using that will make designing things easier.

Comment: Ok, overflow: scroll; is pretty straightforward but if I'd like to get rid of the browser scrollbar, how do I link a button so it jump's to an #id inside another div? I think I can workout getting the #id for the buttons but what do I actually link it to?

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot and it's working now. Don't know how I mucked up but the button (in javascript) wasn't working and now it is. Thank you for your help!